# How can I return AJAX response text?

Tags: javascript, ajax

For the sake of better organized code, instead of putting a callback function within my req.onreadystatechange handler, I'd like to simply return the data.

In the following javascript, the "raw_data" var is undefined because parse_data() function is called before the ajax response.

```
function dostuff(){
   var raw_data = ajax_fetch_data();
   var parsed_data = parse_data(raw_data);
}
```

Is it possible to not call parse_data() until the req.onreadystatechange within the ajax_fetch_data() returns data?

I don't like having the parse_data() call nested as a callback within ajax_fetch_data().

Comment: Don't tell him that.  Now he is going to go back and accept a random answer to all of his questions.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that everyone. I somehow overlooked the fact that your supposed to accept an answer. Thought answer quality was simply reflected by their vote count. I'll make sure to go back and accept the right answers to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A in Ajax means "asynchronous". If your call is asynchronous, it is not possible to use a return value like that. You have to wait for the event with a callback. However, you can send a synchronous request like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open('GET', 'http://www.example.org/', false);
req.send(null);  
if(req.status == 200)  
    return req.responseText;
```

where the `false` on the second line specifies the synchronous nature (default value of the third argument is `true`).

There is more at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Wrong.  It is possible to create a synchronous request.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've altered the answer to include synchronous requests. Let me know if you spot any more errors.

Comment: You're answer still implies that what makeee wants to do is impossible, but then you follow it up with an example of how to do exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: Thanks. I've rewritten it slightly in line with what you said.

Answer (score 1):

This code is overly vague:
   var raw_data = ajax_fetch_data();

Usually it's like this:

```
// url = ...
// data = ...
create_ajax_request(url, data, callback);
// This will continue to execute like normal
// ...
// ...
// ...

// Now, in a differnt part of the code:
function callback() {
    // Sometime later, when AJAX returns data, this is called.
}
```

So essentially you have two threads: the main program where you "start" a request, and the callback function that gets called when the request is complete.  This still ignores the details.

If you want SJAX (a bad abbreviation for syncronous javascript & xml), then you could use something like jQuery:

```
var result = null;
$.ajax({
    aync: false,
    data: data,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
// result is populated before $.ajax() moves on, so you can use it right after
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

However, this performs a busy-wait (ie. your browser is stuck/locked-up until the data comes in... could be a few ms, could be a minute, who knows).  So this should only be used when necessary.  If you just want to get data and then process it, use callbacks.

```
// Call this to start a request
function startRequest() {
    data = ...
    create_ajax_request(url, data, continueRequest);
}

// This is called once we have the data
function continueRequest(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

This is more typical of AJAX programs.